# My app in firefox and internet explorer looks zoomed in. Is there a viewport setting the load the website more zoomed out?

Tags: html, css, viewport

My app in firefox and internet explorer looks zoomed in. Is there a viewport setting the load the website more zoomed out?

**This is my current index.html settings in my angular 2 app:**

```
    <base href="/"></base>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="fragment" content="!"/>
    <meta name="application-name" content="test"/>
    <meta name="description" content="test"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="test"/>
    <meta content="IE=edge, chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
```

```
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon32.png" sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon96.png" sizes="96x96">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon16.png" sizes="16x16">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Comment: it didnt make a difference. Basically, I want all the browsers to look the same on load. Currently firefox and ie are zoomed in more than chrome. Maybe its not the viewport?

Comment: I am not sure... Include a plunker in your question to help others reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a layout width that's wider than the device screen, e.g:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=980">
```

The browser will only zoom out as far as there's content so I'm guessing what's happening now is that all your content is narrow and the browser can't zoom out any more. Setting the width in the viewport `<meta>` will make the `<html>` element fill that width so the browser should be able to zoom out further, assuming you're using a screen that's less than 980 CSS pixels wide (in the example above).

Answer (score 0):

As per [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh708740(v=vs.85).aspx), I used the following code to set my viewport to the zoom level (or lack thereof) that I wanted:

```
@-ms-viewport {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
}
```

I'm working on a horizontal scrolling website/infographic, which is just a single page, and having it zoom in was totally ruining the experience. This worked for me!